# Replace node DotnetRDF

Tags: rdf, sparql, dotnetrdf

I am trying to modify a Rdf node using dotNetRDF, then save it in a new file, but i am getting the same file !!

i would like to change Identification/12  to Identification/18.

**The template file :**

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.
@prefix qudt: <http://qudt.org/schema/qudt#>.
@prefix qudt-unit: <http://qudt.org/vocab/unit#>.
@prefix knr: <http://kurl.org/NET/knr#>.

@prefix keak: <http://kurl.org/NET/keak#>.
@prefix keak-time: <http://kurl.org/NET/keak/time#>.
@prefix keak-eval: <http://kurl.org/NET/keak/eval#>.
@prefix keak-quantity: <http://kurl.org/NET/keak/quantity#>.
@prefix keak-ev: <http://kurl.org/NET/keak/ev#>.

@base <http://data.info/keak/knr/>.

<Identification/12> a keak-ev:Identification.

<Quantity/45> a qudt:Quantity ;
  qudt:quantityType keak-quantity:ElectricConsumption .
```

**The VB.NET code :**

```
Dim gKnr As IGraph = New Graph()
Dim ttlParser As TurtleParser = New TurtleParser()

'Load the file template
ttlParser.Load(gKnr, PATH_TEMPLATE)
gKnr.BaseUri = New Uri(keak_BASE_URI_Knr)

Dim oNode As INode = gKnr.CreateUriNode(New Uri("http://kurl.org/NET/keak/ev#Identification"))

'retrieve the item
Dim listRes As List(Of Triple) = gKnr.GetTriplesWithObject(oNode)
'?s = http://data.info/keak/Knr/Identification/12 , 
'?p = http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type , 
'?o = http://kurl.org/NET/keak/ev#Identification

'modify the item
Dim tIdentification As Triple
If listRes.Count = 1 Then
    tIdentification = listRes(0)
    tIdentification.Subject.GraphUri = New Uri("http://data.info/kseak/knr/Identification/18")

End If

gKnr.Assert(tIdentification)

' Serialisation and Save
Dim ttlWriter As New CompressingTurtleWriter()
ttlWriter.DefaultNamespaces = gKnr.NamespaceMap
ttlWriter.Save(gKnr, PATH_NEW_FILE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work, `GraphUri` is a property of `INode` that indicates which graph a node came from and has nothing to do with the actual URI of the node

Regardless `INode` is immutable and you cannot change the URI of a node as you are attempting to do.

If you wish to change a URI in a RDF graph then you need to `Retract()` all triples that use that URI and create new triples with the new URI and `Assert()` them.

The following example is probably synactically incorrect VB but hopefully it will give you the general idea:

```
Dim listRes As List(Of Triple) = gKnr.GetTriplesWithObject(oNode).ToList()

For Each origTriple in listRes
  gKnr.Retract(origTriple)
  Dim newTriple as Triple
  newTriple = new Triple(New Uri("http://data.info/kseak/knr/Identification/18"), origTriple.Predicate, origTriple.Object)
  gKnr.Assert(newTriple)
Next
```

Of course if the URI you want to change occurs in more than just the subject position then you will need to change the logic appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Thank you robV, it helped me a lot, i got an exception from visual but i managed to correct it, this is the final code:

```
    For Each origTriple In listRes
        gKnr.Retract(origTriple)
        Dim sNode As INode = gKnr.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://data.info/keask/Knr/Identification/18"))
        Dim newTriple As Triple
        newTriple = New Triple(sNode, origTriple.Predicate, origTriple.Object)
        gKnr.Assert(newTriple)
    Next
```